# Report - is something like horizontal union a solution of my task?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, group-by, union

I'd like to group data grouped by few values of the same attribute horizontal.
For example if I have People collection that is implemented like that:

```
  name   group_id  sex 
('Mike', 'A', 'Male') 
('Mark', 'B', 'Male')
('Peter', 'C', 'Male')
('Sarah', 'A', 'Female')
('Dolores', 'A', 'Female')
('Jessica', 'C', 'Female')
```

I could group them by group_id and sex like that:

```
SELECT sex, group_id, COUNT(*) "nr of people"
FROM People
GROUP BY sex, group_id;
```

and get:

```
  sex  group_id  nr of people
Female    A       2
Female    B       0
Female    C       1
Male      A       1
Male      B       1
Male      C       1
```

But I'd like to do something like that in more ellegant, shorter form and present every group as a column like that:

```
Sex    Group A    Group B   Group C
Female     2          0         1
Male       1          1         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CASE` to do conditional counting:

```
SELECT sex,
       sum(case when group_id = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as group_A,
       sum(case when group_id = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as group_B,
       sum(case when group_id = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) as group_C
FROM People
GROUP BY sex;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for.